# @Transactional doesn't update records using HQL or SQL

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, hql

I am using transactional annotation in order to enable auto-commit in Oracle DB.

When I use criteria to update records, I get the record updated successfully. But when I use HQL or SQL, in the console the query is printed but doesn't execute

This is Notification DAO

```
@Repository("SystemUserNotificationDao")
public class SystemUserNotificationDaoImpl extends AbstractDao<BigDecimal, SystemUserNotification> implements SystemUserNotificationDao {

    @Override
    public Number setNotificationsAsSeen() {
        Query query = createHqlQuery("update SystemUserNotification set seen = 1 where seen = 0");
        return (Number)query.executeUpdate();
    }

}
```

This is the service

```
Service("SystemUserNotificationService")
@Transactional
public class SystemUserNotificationServiceImpl implements SystemUserNotificationService {

    @Autowired
    SystemUserNotificationDao systemUserNotificationDao;

    @Override
    public Number setNotificationsAsSeen() {
        return systemUserNotificationDao.setNotificationsAsSeen();
    }
}
```

This is the AbstractDao

```
    public abstract class AbstractDao<PK extends Serializable, T> {

    private final Class<T> persistentClass;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public AbstractDao() {
        this.persistentClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[1];
    }

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T getByKey(PK key) {
        return (T) getSession().get(persistentClass, key);
    }

    public void persist(T entity) {
        getSession().persist(entity);
    }

    public void update(T entity) {
        getSession().update(entity);
    }

    public void saveOrUpdate(T entity) {
        getSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);
    }

    public void delete(T entity) {
        getSession().delete(entity);
    }

    protected Criteria createEntityCriteria() {
        return getSession().createCriteria(persistentClass);
    }

    protected SQLQuery createSqlQuery(String query) {
        return getSession().createSQLQuery(query);
    }

    protected Query createHqlQuery(String query) {
        return getSession().createQuery(query);
    }
}
```

I tried to add transaction.begin and commit but it gives me nested transactions not supported

```
    @Override
    public Number setNotificationsAsSeen() {
//        Query query = createHqlQuery("update SystemUserNotification set seen = 1 where seen = 0");
        Transaction tx = getSession().beginTransaction();
        Query query = getSession().createQuery("update SystemUserNotification set seen = 1 where seen = 0");
        Number n = (Number)query.executeUpdate();
        tx.commit();
        return n;
    }
```

Comment: If the query is logged, then it's executed. But maybe some exception causes a rollback, and you're not seeing that exception. What are the logs you see? What is the value of the returned number? Is `seen` really an integer in your entity, or is it a boolean, or something else?

Comment: I only get the query printed without anything else. If I try to do manual update on the table, I get a waiting for transaction in Oracle SQL dev tool, and when I switch of tomcat, the query executed in SQL dev tool

Comment: So it is executing the query, but it takes a lot of time. You probably have a lock causing the query to wait before being executed, probably because you have made changes using your oracle dev tool and haven't committed the transaction. Close your oracle sql dev tool.

Comment: That's true @JBNizet I closed SQL Dev tool and the transaction committed successfully. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with SQL developer tool. there were uncommitted changes, I closed the dev tool and the update query worked fine